# How to make a div background color smaller than its content?

Tags: html, css

I have this code with this css property. I want to make that gray box smaller than the text inside it, how can I do that?

```css
.media-body {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="media-body">
  <h5>Lagoa Azul</h5>
  <span class="texto-media-body">
    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla 
    vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin.
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Background color covers the whole element. While there is the `background-size` property, it [only applies to background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

To over come this use a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) for the background

```css
.media-body {
  position  : relative;         /* Make any child element will be positioned relative to this container */
  border    : 1px solid black;
}

.media-body::before {
  content          : '';       /* Set empty content                      */
  position         : absolute; /* Position the pseudo-element absolutely */
  height           : 90%;      /* Set height and width as desired        */
  width            : 90%;
  top              : 5%;       /* Set the offset as desired              */
  left             : 5%;
  z-index          : -1;       /* Send element to back                   */
  background-color : gray;  
}
```

```html
<div class="media-body">
  <h5>Lagoa Azul</h5>
  <span class="texto-media-body">
    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla 
    vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin.
  </span>
</div>
```